# How to import swagger model barrel file in Typescript (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger

We are currently automatically generating our API models with swagger and want to import them convenient into our project.

At the moment we import it in the following way:
tsconfig.ts

```
"paths": {
  "apimodel/*": ["frontend/swagger-api-definition/model/*"]
}
```

Random data-source class:

```
import { ExampleDtoQuery } from 'apimodel/exampleDtoQuery ';
import { ExampleUserDtosUserManagerDashboardResponseUserProject } from 'apimodel/exampleUserDtosUserManagerDashboardResponseUserProject ';
```

Names are just random, do not judge them please :)

Now what I would like to do, is to create an alias in the tsconfig and use the barrel file, which is generated in the root. Like so:
tsconfig.ts

```
"paths": {
  "@apimodel": ["frontend/swagger-api-definition/index.ts"]
},
```

Random data-source class:

```
import { ExampleDtoQuery } from '@apimodel';
import { ExampleUserDtosUserManagerDashboardResponseUserProject } from '@apimodel ';
```

But the compiler keeps telling me: `Cannot find module '@apimodel'.ts(2307)`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` in the path definition tells the TS compiler to allow imports from anything with the prefix `@apimodel/`. You also need to provide a `baseUrl` or it the TS compiler will not be able to find the barrel file in question. To make it work the way you want you should be able to update the `paths` and `baseUrl` definitions to be:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "@apimodel": ["frontend/swagger-api-definition/index.ts"]
},
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I tried this also, but copied the wrong line. Still getting `Cannot find module '@apimodel'.ts(2307)`

Comment: You also need to specify a `baseUrl` I have updated my answer.